# Show confirmation textbox after entry with JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Before we begin, I would like to convey that I have limited to no knowledge on the JavaScript language. The only things I've used is JQueryUI - and even that is copy paste.

Currently, I have a user registration page, with all the standard `TextBox` inputs. I would like to, however, slide down a secondary 'Confirm email' and 'confirm password' whenever a user enters text into the original text box.

I understand the community likes to help those who can prove they helped themselves, but the only thing I currently have to show is me *trying* to lookup solutions for this and failing.

Could someone please show me a way to do this?

**Edit: Code of the password box**

```
<div class="ctrlHolder">
    <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" CssClass="styleLabelWatermarkWashout" Text="**********"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <%--data-default-value="Placeholder text"--%>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRegisterPassword" runat="server" CssClass="textInput styleTextBoxCenter required"
        TextMode="Password" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Comment: The style of the site doesnt allow for text boxes to be placed next to each other, if that makes sense? Also, its a 'minimalistic' type of site, so the less space used, the better. So, I decided to want to show the confirmations only when needed. I wanted to use javascript for the effect of showing/hiding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a reference to jquery to the page you are working on.
Then make a new script (on the page or in a separate `.js` file) which attaches a new function to the onkeyup event for the textboxes. Something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('mytextbox').bind('keyup', function() { 
        $('myCOnfirmationTextbox').slideDown();
    };
});
```

This will attach this function to all elements corresponding to the "mytextbox" class or ID. So if you have an input `<input type="text" id="email" class="emailInput"/>` then you would use `$('#email')` to bind the event to this particular element. Or you use `$('.Emailinput')` to bind to all input elements for emails.

By the way, I haven't tested the code, but this or something very similar should work.

If you use a separate `.js` file, then don't forget to reference it in your page as well.

Comment: Does the second text box have to be hidden?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I forgot to mention that. It has to be hidden using css or js at first, so that you can unhide it later. JQuery has lots of functions to reveal hidden content, like slide, fade, show etc. Google those keywords and you will find loads of explanations on how to use them :)

Comment: After I initially put `hidden=true`, it works perfectly :D Thanks! :D

Comment: If the second input is always visible then your style is not being applied correctly... I would have a look at it without the script at first to make sure everything is displayed correctly. You should the hidden element in the page source, but not on the page.

Comment: I take it it worked then? By the way, Tieson made a good point about keyup and blur, which you might want to take into account for refining this depending on your needs.

Comment: It worked :) Will look at the other answers an implement it !

Answer (score 2):

So, assuming you can create markup similar to this:

```
<div class="ctrlHolder">
    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" CssClass="styleLabelWatermarkWashout" Text="**********"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <%--data-default-value="Placeholder text"--%>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRegisterPassword" runat="server" CssClass="textInput styleTextBoxCenter required" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

<div id="confirm-password-box" class="ctrlHolder">
    <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Confirm Password"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" CssClass="styleLabelWatermarkWashout" Text="**********"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <%--data-default-value="Placeholder text"--%>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmRegisterPassword" runat="server" CssClass="textInput styleTextBoxCenter required" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

You'd want to add some CSS rules to make `#confirm-password-box` hidden by default. Then, add this script code somewhere on the page (preferably as close to closing `</body>` tag as possible):

```
<script>

$(function(){

    $('#<%: txtRegisterPassword.ClientID %>').on('blur', function(event){

        $('#confirm-password-box').slideToggle('slow');

    });

});

</script>
```

The `blur` event occurs when the control loses focus. You don't really want to listen for `keyup`, since that would require this code being called every time a user entered a character into the password box...

Note that this particular chunk of jQuery code requires **jQuery 1.7 or higher**, so use NuGet to update your script reference (if you're not using anything else that requires an older version of jQuery).

Comment: Good point with keyup, I didn't think if that in my hast to answer. Although you could have a bool variable to make sure the code only executes once ;)

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer! Unfortunatly, the confirmation box slides open about 10% then disappears! I'm checking now to see if I never made an ignorant error. You said to `(preferably as close to closing </body> tag as possible)`.. May I ask why?

Comment: @NewAmbition It's less of an issue with modern browsers, but older browsers tend to load resources/run scripts in a more-or-less serial manner, so any scripts you add can slow down the rendering of the page content. Moving scripts to the very end (when/where appropriate) can give your users a better experience. As for the height issue, I think that happens if the content being slid doesn't have a height specified.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - and thanks for the advice :D The 'height' issue was because the text box was in a Ajax Update Panel, and it kept refreshing after postback - turning that off fixed it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use innerHTML to have a new textbox beneath the email textbox once that box is filled. I could give you the code if you can post the code over here

Comment: Added the code for the password box.. If thats what you asked for?

Answer (score 0):

- Replace the controls ids in this answer as per your html.

You can show the confirm controls in the following way.

```
 $('#password').onfocusout(function() {   
      // This will show once you complete entering Email and Password.
      $('#confirmEmail').attr('display', 'inline');
      $('#confirmPassword').attr('display', 'inline');
    });
```

Let me tell how you can achieve confirm Email. Same thing can be used to achieve confirm password.

When you focus out of confirm email textbox compare the emails entered by the user in Email and Confirm Email textboxex.

This can be done in following way

```
$('#confirmEmail').onfocusout(function() {
  if($('#confirmEmail').val() == $('#Email').val())
{
      // Emails entered are same
}
else
{
     alert('Emails entered are not matching. Please reenter emails.');
}
});
```

Similarly you can check for confirm password.