# Javascript Database Validation with Ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation

Thanks to [my previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303614/show-confirmation-textbox-after-entry-with-javascript), I have successfully shown a new Textbox after a users enters text in a previous TextBox.

Now, I would like to only show the new TextBox after the text in the original TextBox has been validated.
The validation will make sure the data in the original TextBox is not in the database.

The text boxes are in an `Ajax Update Panel`. Unfortunatly, I can not use `AutoPostBack` events, because it effectively resets the JavaScript, even when using `function pageLoad()`
.

I would like to use the JavaScript to validate against the database, and so far used this code:

**JavaScript on Text.aspx**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad() {
            $('#<%: txtRegisterEmail.ClientID %>').on('blur', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Test.aspx/CheckEmail",
                    data: "{Email: '" + ('#<%: txtRegisterEmail.ClientID %>').value + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    failure: function(response) {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        function OnSuccess(response) {
            $('#<%: txtRegisterEmailConfirm.ClientID %>').slideDown();
        }
        //'input[name$="txtRegisterEmailConfirm"]'
    </script>
```

**Test.aspx.cs**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static bool CheckEmail(string Email)
{
    int counter = 0;
    const string strSql = "SELECT memberEmail FROM vwGetMemberDetails";

    using (SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(strSql, DataConn.Connect()) { CommandType = CommandType.Text })
    {
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = sqlComm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return counter > 0;
}
```

The only thing this code does is show the text box (seemingly without validation).
How can I make this work?

Comment: side note: is there any reason you're not doing SELECT COUNT( memberEmail) FROM vwGetMemberDetails where memberEmail=@email and then passing in a SqlParameter? Then you can do ExecuteScalar to get the count value.

Comment: Very good observation :) I will remember that next time I have to count rows.. As for this, I just needed to use HasRows()..